# How to list the IPv6 of a Kubernethes service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, ipv6, kubectl

I am running a Kubernethes cluster with many services,  I am getting the IPv4 using the command:

```
kubectl get svc
```

But I need also IPv6,  how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

[IPv6 is currently not supported by Kubernetes.](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/networking.md#ipv6)